# qtcreator project file depndancies and build order

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am using qtcreator with subdir project structure. The case is that:
I have 2 projects. Project A and B. After A compiles, then B, but in B, I must use the headers of A (classes, functions, etc.). I`ve found in wiki the depends and subdir project setup, but when I try to include class A from project A into class B into project B ( these names are for convininece ) it gives me undefined referencies. Here is my .pro file from main project (and subprojects respectively ):

```
#base pro file
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    message \
    daemon \
    receiver


daemon.subdir = daemon
message.subdir = message
daemon.depends = message
```

subproject A:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    daemon.cpp \
    logwriter.cpp

HEADERS += \
    daemon.h \
    logwriter.h \
    defs.h

LIBS += -lpthread
```

subproject B:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    message.cpp \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    message.h
```

So I need the project B classes into project A and further on when I extend the project. 
Regards.
**EDIT**: A .pri example would be appreciated, if I'm going to set project A to be a library (-lclssA )

Answer (score 1):

"undefined references" are generally link problems, not header include problems. You may have to link your project A with B if you need to use it.
e.g in A :

```
LIBS += ../path/to/libB.so
```

Comment: When I individually build the .cpp files from project B they are built. Also my projects are not libs. Must I build the dependency project as lib? I don`t want to do that though. So I want to know if qtcreator project can make this.

Comment: But you are right, the .so lib works, however, if I can`t find a workaround, I`ll make it a lib...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to include it as a lib, the easiest way was from qtcreator, rightclick on the dependee and "Add library" -> "Existing library from build tree". This will generate the following in the .pro:

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../message/release/ -lmessage
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../message/debug/ -lmessage
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../message/ -lmessage

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../message
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../message
```

However I am losing the ability to make tests for my message class in it's main class. So if there is a better way, I'd accept it.